# What is the symfony deubg toolbar trying to tell me?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

What is the debugger trying to tell me from that red notification in the toolbar?
[image: debugger]

When i clicked it, it showed me some papping errors. Why is it an error?

[image: detail info]

Category Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ewaste_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Category
{


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Type", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $type;
}
```

Model Entity

```
class Model
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="model")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="model_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $type;
}
```

Type entity

```
class Type
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Model", mappedBy="model")
     */
    protected $model;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.
I changed the $type to $model in Model Entity

Answer (score 0):

You should check your doctrine mapping configuration specialy indexedBy and mappedBy properties

Answer (score 0):

You have an entity named `Type` that has a relationship with another entity named `Model`.
Somewhere in `Type` you have an association that tries to map to a field that should be into `Model` entity (named model itself) that isn't there. This is first error you're seeing here.

Second error talks about `Model` entity. It says that the association between `Category` and `Model` and `Model` And `Type` are not consistent, so you're using some fields for mappings that aren't correct.

Could you paste those three entities so we can provide you a solution also?

Comment: @SushantBajracharya: don't you have any primary key into your entities?

Comment: yes I have but I only included the relationships here. Should I include the primary keys too? they basically are just ids thats all so i did not included them in here